# Full disk encryption on CentOS 9 Stream with TPM2 decryption at boot time

Tags: centos, boot, luks, tpm

I'm working on provisioning a server that requires full drive encryption and I want to automate the process of decrypting the drive at startup using the TPM2 module available on the motherboard, but I can't quite get the system to do so.
I have a fresh install of CentOS 9 Stream that was created uing automated LVM partitioning of the only available drive, and it was encrypted as a LUKSv2.

After the installation of the OS, I made sure that `clevis`, `clevis-luks`, and `dracut` were installed. I also installed `clevis-systemd` and `clevis-udisks2` just in case.

At this stage, running `tpm2_pcrread` reported the expected registers.

Then I binded the drive to clevis using the following command:

```
sudo clevis luks bind -d /dev/<drive> tmp2 '{"pcr_bank":"sha256","pcr_ids":"0,1,7"}'
```

No issue so far.

I then created a dracut config named `tpm2.conf` in `/etc/dracut.config.d/` with:

```
add_dracutmodules+=" clevis clevis-pin-tpm2 crypt tpm2-tss "
install_items+=" /usr/bin/clevis "
hostonly="yes"
```

Then ran:

```
sudo dracut -f
```

At this stage, I thought that was all I needed, but it seems like it wasn't enough.

I then tried to boot with the grub options `rd.luks.options=<luks-UUID>=tpm2-device=auto` but that did nothing.

Any idea of what could be the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/security_hardening/index#configuring-manual-enrollment-of-volumes-using-tpm2_configuring-automated-unlocking-of-encrypted-volumes-using-policy-based-decryption), no file in /etc/dracut.config.d/ is necessary. Try removing that file you created and regenerating the initramfs with `dracut -f --regenerate-all`.

If after doing that and rebooting it still does not work automatically decrypt the container (sometimes you need to be a bit patient, wait some time before entering the passphrase), then please post the output of both lsblk and of clevis luks list -d /dev/yourblockdevice you bound to the tpm2 chip.